# Setter analogues of `MultibodyTree::get_positions_from_array()` and `MultibodyTree::get_velocities_from_array()`

Tags: drake

There do not seem to be analogous setters. If I want to fill in the relevant pieces of an array, is there an interface for doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Three ways of doing this:

1. Using the joint specific APIs as in the example [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/multibody/acrobot/passive_simulation.cc#L100).
2. For free bodies you can use the plant's API as [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/examples/multibody/cylinder_with_multicontact/cylinder_run_dynamics.cc#L133).
3. If you know what you are doing, you can play with the state vector as done [here](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/master/multibody/multibody_tree/multibody_plant/test/multibody_plant_test.cc#L1780).

Answer (score 0):

I added methods to provide exactly this functionality in this PR: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/9503